# MongoDB $or many orders of magnitude slower than single queries

Tags: performance, mongodb, logical-operators

When querying 10K objects, it appears that querying each object individually with a find_one is much faster than `$or`-ing the queries together, which doesn't make much sense. Is there something wrong with the following making things slow? The query seems to hang for a while for the first 200 or so objects, and then finds all the rest very quickly.

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import com.mongodb.BasicDBObject;
import com.mongodb.DBCollection;
import com.mongodb.DBCursor;
import com.mongodb.DBObject;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MongoOrVsSingleQuery {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MongoClient mc = new MongoClient();
        mc.getDB("foo").dropDatabase();
        DBCollection foo = mc.getDB("foo").getCollection("foo");
        DBObject index = new BasicDBObject("a", 1);
        index.put("b", 1);
        foo.ensureIndex(index);
        List<DBObject> lo = new LinkedList<DBObject>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 10001; i++) {
            DBObject o = new BasicDBObject("a", i);
            o.put("b", 1);
            lo.add(o);
        }
        System.out.println("insert: " + new Date());
        foo.insert(lo);
        for (DBObject o: lo) {
            o.removeField("_id");   
        }
        DBObject query = new BasicDBObject("$or", lo);
        System.out.println("find one: " + new Date());
        for (DBObject o: lo) {
            foo.findOne(o).get("a");
        }
        System.out.println("find: " + new Date());
        DBCursor dbc = foo.find(query);
        for (DBObject o: dbc) {
            if ((int) o.get("a") % 100 == 0) {
                System.out.println("find obj: " + o.get("a") + " " + new Date());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("done: " + new Date());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
insert: Tue Nov 19 07:16:02 PST 2013
find one: Tue Nov 19 07:16:02 PST 2013
find: Tue Nov 19 07:16:05 PST 2013
find obj: 100 Tue Nov 19 07:16:08 PST 2013
find obj: 200 Tue Nov 19 07:21:22 PST 2013
find obj: 300 Tue Nov 19 07:21:22 PST 2013
*snip*
find obj: 9900 Tue Nov 19 07:21:22 PST 2013
find obj: 10000 Tue Nov 19 07:21:22 PST 2013
done: Tue Nov 19 07:21:22 PST 2013
```

During the query, this is typical output of currentOp():

```
~$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.3
connecting to: test
> use foo
> db.currentOp()
{
    "inprog" : [
        {
            "opid" : 40221,
            "active" : true,
            "secs_running" : 241,
            "op" : "getmore",
            "ns" : "foo.foo",
            "query" : {
                "$msg" : "query not recording (too large)"
            },
            "client" : "127.0.0.1:58696",
            "desc" : "conn7",
            "threadId" : "0x7fef961f8700",
            "connectionId" : 7,
            "locks" : {
                "^" : "r",
                "^foo" : "R"
            },
            "waitingForLock" : false,
            "numYields" : 124,
            "lockStats" : {
                "timeLockedMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(390668733),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                },
                "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
                    "r" : NumberLong(195362976),
                    "w" : NumberLong(0)
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
> db.version()
2.4.3
```

Comment: Sure it makes sense, an $or is spearate clauses like running two find_ones but then the results are merged back to omit duplicates, so server-side when you measure within mongodb itself each query will be faster

Comment: @Sammaye If I'm reading your comment correctly, you're saying that the merge time accounts for the 3s to do 10K findOnes vs. 5m to run an $or with 10K entries? If that's the case, it seems like it's always going to be more efficient to run findOne() if there are a large number of queries.

Comment: There is no merge time for separate find_ones, the merge is when you use an $or since each clause of the $or effectively is a new query, so MongoDB runs the query and merges duplicates on its side. It is possible that it could take a very long time with 10K entries. Yes it is likely that a find_one will be more efficient 90% of the time when there are a large number of queries

Comment: @Sammaye Hm. So what's the point of `$or` then? When *should* one use an `$or` rather than multiple queries?

Comment: Hmm, when you have a complex query that cannot be satisfied by two separate ones. For example the way you are using it is to select a matrix of data using more like a $in clause actually from what I gather (I don't read Java well) while an $or is more like ability to find only one result using two different clauses...hmm that doesn't help but yeah

Comment: For me it sounds crazy to have a query with 10000 or conditions. Even 100 is too much. I suppose most optimizers (DB2, Oracle, MySQL) would get mad, too.